# Related to mySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing a website where user enters the amount in  the table recieved by clients and if any client does not given installments (amount) then user does not enter any amount in the table and the user wants to get informatin of the defaulter clients based on 10 days. so my question is that what table and attributes should be defined to handle this situation.

My Tables are

> Clients (cId, name, advance, discount, balance)
>
> Installments(id, date, amount, cId)

but through installments table, I am not getting how to generate report of those who dosen't given any payment for 10 days b/c as I said user dosen't insert data of defaulters in installments table.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you enter the details of paid instalments. You should have some additional field. `paid_status, paid_date` to fetch these details easily.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what format your `installments.date` field is. Here's how you can sort by most recent date for a client with `cid = 1`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM installments i
INNER JOIN clients c ON c.cid = i.cid
WHERE c.cid = 1
ORDER BY i.date DESC
```

How is the `installments.date` field formatted? Is it a datetime string (e.g. `'2007-12-15 23:50:26'`), a UNIX timestamp (e.g. `1111885200`), or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select * from clients where cid in (select cid from installments where amount is null and (date between DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -10 DAY) and curdate())
```

[Date_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) will be helpful to get the details of last 10 days and then add one more condition, who haven't paid anything in those days.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add `nextPaymentDate` for `Client`'s table like:

```
Clients (cId, name, advance, discount, balance, nextPaymentDate)
```

So, that you could query like

```
SELECT * FROM Clients
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),nextPaymentDate) >= 10;
```

You will still have the detail of payments in your `Installments` table but every time a client made a payment then `nextPaymentDate` is updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM installments i
right JOIN clients c ON c.cid = i.cid
WHERE date between DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -10 DAY) and curdate()
```